# Using PayPal Parallel payment in combination with Chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need a way to use PayPal's Parallel payment in combination with Chained payments. From what I can sift from their perplexing documentation this doesn't appear to be possible.

Essentially what I want is:

```
         Primary A (visible) > Secondary (hidden)
Sender >
         Primary B (visible)
```

Ordinarily Chained payments would be fine, but I want the sender to see the amount going to Primary A and Primary B when he gets redirected to PayPal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel and Chained Payments have similar functions but are different from each other. Both are used to send money to multiple recipients but with Chained Payments the buyer would only see the primary receiver. With Parallel Payments the buyer would see every receiver.

You should be able to use just Parallel Payments just fine. The buyer wouldn't just see the amount of money being sent to the extra recipients though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However in my chart above, I want the buyer to see the $ going to Primary A and Primary B, but not Secondary. I don't believe this is possible with Parallel.

Comment: Oh, I get. You can only define a single Primary receiver and that is the problem here. You want the payment to be sent to three people and only two of them to be visible. There isn't a way to do that. I'll submit a Feature Request but I can't guarantee that it will be implemented - sorry.